# Azure VM Bandwidth Limit

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine on Azure and I was wondering if there is a bandwidth limit for it.
By bandwidth limit I mean, a limit like 15GB of outbound and inbound data transfer.
I tried checking some forums about this but could not find a clear answer.

Comment: What do you mean by bandwidth limit? Please edit your question and elaborate more.

Comment: Ok, i have edited it.

Comment: This is not a programming question belonging on Stack Overflow. You might expose your question to a more helpful audience on [https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [https://webapps.stackexchange.com/](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). Cheers

Comment: Or better yet, try [https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as your VM will be on shared infrastructure, there are bandwidth limits for your VM. And the bandwidth is metered on **egress (outbound) only** and not on the ingress (inbound).

Further the bandwidth depends on your VM Size. The below link gives the network bandwidth limit of Dav4 and Dasv4-series

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dav4-dasv4-series

[image]

For more information on Virtual Machine network bandwidth,

refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-machine-network-throughput

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. Bandwidth is measured for both ingress and egress. There are pricing differences (e.g. initial 5GB of monthly ingress included without being charged), but they're both metered.

Comment: as per Microsoft docs here - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-machine-network-throughput], only egress are metered for Virtual Machine's network throughput. *"Ingress is not metered or limited directly. However, there are other factors, such as CPU and storage limits, which can impact a virtual machine’s ability to process incoming data."* Can you please share some pointers if this is not the case

Comment: I'm not saying *throttled.* I'm talking from a "you can see your ingress and egress numbers, as they are metered" perspective. It's not an unknown. But also, there are ingress costs beyond 5GB monthly (it's something people should be aware of). All that aside: note that this isn't a question for Stack Overflow (it's really something for ServerFault). And as you pointed out: fully covered with existing documentation.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - True, it is not unknown. I was really curious about the monthly 5GB free limit as even the price calculator of Azure for bandwidth is referring to ingress as Free [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/] - and hence asked for some pointers. and yes, maybe this question sits well in ServerFault :) Cheers!

Comment: Sorry - not enough coffee this morning - I was indeed talking about *outbound* 5GB for free, not *inbound.* Point still stands on metering though (that you can see your measured ingress). But correct, there is no inbound per-GB cost.